# Sequelize Reuse Query in another query

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a query in another function that I want to reuse in a WITH clause of another query. I tried something like the code below.

Code to give the rough idea.

```
const reuseQuery = async (IdType, eventID) => {
    try {
        const sqlQuery = `SELECT *
        FROM TableA TA 
        WHERE TA.IdType = :IdType AND TA.eventID = :eventID`;
        const replacements = {IdType, eventID};
        const result = await this.sequelize.query(sqlQuery, {replacements, type: this.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};


const useReuseQuery = async () => {
    try {
        const sqlQuery = `WITH Query1 AS (${await reuseQuery(1, 1)}),
        Query2 AS (${await reuseQuery(2, 1)})
        Select q1.name AS Captain, q2.name AS Player
        FROM Query1 q1, Query2 q2
        WHERE q1.partnerID = q2.ID AND q2.partnerID = q1.ID`;

        const result = await this.sequelize.query(sqlQuery, {type: this.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
        return result;
    } catch(error) {
        
    }
};
```

When I try that I get the error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd function, you're concating two result sets into a query string, which won't work.  AFAIK, that will not make valid SQL.

Better to concat the 1st sqlQuery twice into the 2nd sqlQuery, roughly as follows:

```
const reusableSqlQuery = `SELECT *
    FROM TableA TA 
    WHERE TA.IdType = :IdType AND TA.eventID = :eventID`;

const useReuseQuery = async () => {
try {
    const sqlQuery = `WITH Query1 AS (` + reusableSqlQuery +`),
    Query2 AS (` + reusableSqlQuery +`)
    Select q1.name AS Captain, q2.name AS Player
    FROM Query1 q1, Query2 q2
    WHERE q1.partnerID = q2.ID AND q2.partnerID = q1.ID`;
    const replacements = {1,1,2,1};
    const result = await this.sequelize.query(sqlQuery, {replacements, type: this.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
    return result;
} catch(error) {
    
}
```

};